# How to chop a function?

Tags: functions

Suppose I want to write a function that produces small values. I know the **Chop** can be used to treat very small numbers as zeros. How do I force the small output of a function to be automatically zero (i.e. not every time I evaluate the function)

Also, Is there any command that I could add once in the begining of the notebook so that every number (in a function or array) that goes below some threshold automatically evaluate to zero?

Example is

```
f[x_] = 10^-300*x
```

and what I want to do is something like this

```
f[x_] = Chop[f[x],10^-16]
```

which clearly doesn't work

Comment: Maybe the  `Clip`?

Comment: According to the documentation it looks like Chop. Is there any specific way to apply to function? Not function output

Comment: The `Chop` doesn't work in your example because you used infinite precision numbers rather than reals and you used `Set` rather than `SetDelayed`. Use `f[x_] := Chop[(10^-300)*x]`, then  `f /@ (10.^(100 Range[4]))` evaluates to `{0, 0, 1., 9.99999999999997*10^99}`

Answer (score 1):

There is a variable named "$Post". If you give this variable a value of a function, this function is applied to every output.

Further, Chop does not act on accurate numbers. To make it do it, you must first change the number to a machine number.

Here is how you would proceed: Set

```
$Post = Chop[N@#, 10^-16] &
```

From now on until every output of the current session will be truncated. E.g.:

```
10^-10 10^-7.
(* 0 *)

Cos[Pi/2 + 10^-17]
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity how did you come across this variable? I knew one must exist but wasn't sure how to search / find it

Comment: @IntroductionToProbability I must say your user name made me laugh so hard!

Comment: @ IntroductionToProbability  I already used $Pre  once and then it was no big jump to assume that $Post exists.

Comment: @DanielHuber Ah that makes sense. Thanks for highlighting it

Comment: @XXX1010 Glad I could entertain :)